# Issues while publishing web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I developed a web application (code first/entity framework/MVC pattern) and now I got some issues while I am trying to publish it (azure), I enabled custom errors in my webconfig so I can realise which errors I am dealing with, and there it is:

*"An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code."*

[image: Screen shot]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Port 3306 is you MySQL server. There is a problem with your MySQL permissions. I suggest you to check the credentials for the user you are using to access your databases.

Comment: Are you publishing in Azure VM or Azure App Service?

Comment: Azure App Service

Comment: Is your MySQL server up and running?

Comment: Where's your MySQL server hosted? I'm guessing you've been testing with local MySQL instance, and when you published it you haven't changed the server address to your internet-facing address.

Comment: The server is running, Prajwal. And yes Martheen, I haven't changed anything. Could you help me?

Comment: If the site is running on Azure, your DB must be accessible from internet, and you must set the the connection string accordingly. Create one [through Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-php-create-mysql-database) or just pick any MySQL host.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, MySQL host is pointing loop-back/ localhost address (127.0.0.1). 
If you have a separate MySql instance/ host in Azure, make sure that the connection string is pointing to it.

Alternatively, You can use MySql utilities under Kudu Debug console http://yourwebappname.SCM.azurewebsites.net to troubleshoot the error.